# Uses deprecated method java/lang/Integer::<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, oop, math, java-8, jvm

I am working on java version upgrade and I have to fix following statement :

Message: class masthead/auth/mesdb/MesDbAuthLogDAO uses deprecated method java/lang/Integer::(Ljava/lang/String;)V

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast(String code, long period) throws Exception {
        **Object params = new ObjectPair(new Integer(code), new MesDbUtil(ibatis).getPastMesDbDate(period));**
        List mesdbLogs = client.queryForList("LcrLog.getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast", params);
        Iterator mesdbLogsIter = mesdbLogs.iterator();
        List results = new ArrayList();
        while (mesdbLogsIter.hasNext()) {
            MesDbLcrLog mesdbLog = (MesDbLcrLog) mesdbLogsIter.next();
            results.add(mesdbLog.getLog());
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Need to replace that Integer to stop that message to show up.

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Try replacing `new Integer(code)` with `Integer.valueOf(code)`.

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Integer​(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)): *"**Deprecated.** It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Use `parseInt(String)` to convert a string to a `int` primitive, or use `valueOf(String)` to convert a string to an `Integer` object."*

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle can you tell me how in above code please I pretty new in Java

Answer (score 3):

Replace `new Integer(code)` with `Integer.valueOf(code)`. Same thing applies to other wrappers like `Long`, `Double` and so on.

Comment: Really appreciated for your response but can you just tell me how I can do that in above code pleas.

Comment: I just wrote it in the answer... Replace `new Integer(code)` with `Integer.valueOf(code)`.